# PHP PDO Connection

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I want create a connection class for database connection using PDO in PHP

here is my code :

```
<?php
class DatabaseConnection {

private $dbname     = "db_01";
private $host       = "localhost";
private $user       = "xxx";
private $password   = "xxxxxx";
private $port       = 5432;

private $DBH;

public function __construct() {
    try {
        $this->DBH  = new PDO("pgsql:host=$this->host;port=$this->port;dbname=$this->dbname;user=$this->user;password=$this->password");
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo    $e->getMessage();  
    }

}
public function disconnect() {
    $this->DBH  = null; 
}
}
?>
```

For query in PDO i must use $DBH->query('SELECT * from user');

but how if i user my connection class in other class ?

example

```
<?php
include "DatabaseConnection.php";
class User {
    private $connection;

    public function getUser() {
        $this->connection = new DatabaseConnection();
        $STH = $this->connection->query('SELECT * from User');
    }
}
?>
```

But it's not work.

Any body can help me ? Thanks :)

**UPDATE** :

After follow Jonah suggest,

```
<?php

class DatabaseConnection extends PDO {

private $dbname     = "db_01";
private $host       = "localhost";
private $user       = "xxx";
private $password   = "xxxxxxxxx";
private $port       = 5432;

public function __construct() {
    try {
        parent::__construct("pgsql:host=$this->host;port=$this->port;dbname=$this->dbname;user=$this->user;password=$this->password");
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo    $e->getMessage();  
    }

}
public function disconnect() {
    $this = null;   
}
}
?>
```

i got message "The connection was reset" in browser, whats wrong ?

Comment: Could you provide the error message or a description of what exactly fails? My Guess at the moment is, that there is no method named `query` in the `DatabaseConnection`-class.

Comment: @vstm : no, nothing appear, just got nothing. have you PDO before ?

Comment: If nothing is displayed then there are eventually no errors and your script does not produce any output. On the other hand PHP could be suppressing error messages. Check in your php.ini if `display_errors` is **on** and `error_reporting` is set to `E_ALL | E_STRICT`. If `display_errors` is on and there's still no output you should add `echo "hello world";` to check if the script runs properly.

Answer (score 4):

That won't work.  You either need to create a method that calls `query` in PDO:

```
class DatabaseConnection {
    // ...
    public function query($sql) {
        return $this->DBH->query($sql);
    }
    // ...
}
```

or extend PDO.

```
class DatabaseConnection extends PDO {
    // ...
}
```

**Update:**
On the other hand, there is very little point in wrapping the PDO class at all.  Why not just create a PDO object directly?

Comment: what the best, create a query method or extends the PDO it self ?
Thanks

Comment: @Ahmad: It would probably be easier to extend it.  The second bit of code is an example of extending it; just put your other methods into it.

Comment: I Modified my code : public function __construct() {
  try {
   parent::__construct("pgsql:host=$this->host;port=$this->port;dbname=$this->dbname;user=$this->user;password=$this->password");
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
   echo  $e->getMessage();  
  }
  
 }
 public function disconnect() {
  $this = null; 
 }

But i got "The connection was reset" in browser

Answer (score 3):

```
class User {
  private $connection;

  public function __construct ($connection) {
    $this->connection = $connection;
  }

  public function getUser() {
    $STH = $this->connection->query('SELECT * from User');
  }
}
```

Comment: I normally use a variation of this. You can improve it with type hinting.